# The straight distance between the adjacent $n^{\text{th}}$ roots of unity on the unit circle

Tags: complex-numbers

As we know ,the $n^{\text{th}}$ roots of unity are given by the roots of the equation
\begin{align*}
 x^n&=1 \\
 \text{or, }x^n&=e^{2 \pi \iota}
 \end{align*}
Some basic algebra reveals  that the $n$ roots can be written as:
\begin{equation}
  \omega_k=e^{\frac{2 \pi k}{n}\iota},\,\,k=0,1,2,\ldots,n-1
  \end{equation}
We also know that all the $n$ complex numbers given by equation (1) lie on the circle :
$$ \lvert z \rvert=1$$
Further,
$$ \lvert \omega_j-\omega_k \rvert=\left\lvert{\operatorname{cis} \frac{2 \pi j}{n}- \operatorname{cis}\frac{2 \pi k}{n}}\right\rvert,$$
where $\operatorname{cis}\theta=\cos \theta + \iota \sin \theta$.
When $\omega_i$, $\omega_j$ are adjacent vertices of a polygon  then $k=j+1$ so that the above expression becomes

$$\lvert \omega_j-\omega_k \rvert=2\left\lvert \operatorname{cis}\frac{j\pi}{n}-\operatorname{cis}\frac{(j+1)\pi}{n} \right\rvert $$

or,
$$ \lvert \omega_j-\omega_k \rvert=\left|{2 \sin\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{B-A}{2}\right)-2\iota\cos\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right)}\right|$$
where,
$$ A=\frac{2 \pi j}{n}\,, B=\frac{2 \pi (j+1)}{n}.$$
My question is: Since the points $\omega_j$'s $j=0,1,2,\ldots,n-1$ form the vertices of a regular polygon, how do I show that $|\omega_j-\omega_{j+1}| $ is constant for all $j=0,1,2,\ldots, n-1$? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: $\omega_j=\omega^j$ where $\omega=\omega_1$, so $\omega_j-\omega_{j+1}=\omega^j(1-\omega)$.

Comment: As @AnginaSeng pointed out. Multiplication by $\omega$ is equivalent to counterclockwise rotation by $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ and scaling by $1$. Thus the magnitude is invariant of $j$